# Using Json with java returns string with \" instead of "

Tags: java, json

Am using jsonobject and json array and converting the final result to string using `jsonobject.toString()` function and returning the string to browser.

Code snippet:

```
JSONArray VMs= new JSONArray();
JSONObject resultSet = new JSONObject();

for(Vector<String> stages : mrs)
{
    VMs.put(new JSONObject().put("Vm",stages.get(0)));
}

resultSet.append("ServerDetails",(new JSONObject().put("Server",sName).append("Vms", stageNames)));

return resultSet.toString();
```

output on browser:

```
"{\"ServerDetails\":[{\"Server\":\"myserver45\",\"Vms\":[[{\"Vm\":\"vm1022\"},{\"Vm\":\"vm9875\"}]]}]}"
```

I don't want it to return this way. How do i make this return as follows without slashes-

```
"{"ServerDetails":[{"Server":"myserver45","Vms":[[{"Vm":"vm1022"},{"Vm":"vm9875"}]]}]}"
```

I don't understand why `"` gets replaced with `\"` everywhere. Please help.

Comment: Does the quote get escaped in the actual HTTP response (try something like `GET` or `curl`)? Also, which library are you using? More than one has a `JSONArray`/`JSONObject`.

Comment: How did you get that "output on browser"? The backslashes are probably just an artefact of how you output the string.

Comment: @chrylis yes. the quotes are getting escaped.following are the libraries i have used-
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am using @Produces("application/json") and returning the json string from the function. Not sure if that answers your question. Am new to writing codes in java. Am integrating a function returning json string to an already existing code base. Do i have to add anything to pom or web files? Any help in resolving this \" issue is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this output comes from the browser debug console, it's the console adding the backslashes. The important thing is: does this deserialize correctly?

Comment: Also what are you using on the server side? Maybe you're using some sort of framework that expects you to return a `JSONObject` (or some other serializable response object) from your controller directly, not a string. In effect you'd be stringifying the response twice which would cause this behaviour.

Comment: Also do not use `Vector`, the old collection classes are pointlessly synchronized, use ArrayList instead.

Comment: I tried giving resultSet="{\"Server\":\"myserver45\",\"Vms\":[[{\"Vm\":\"vm1022\"},{\"Vm\":\"vm9875\"}]]}]}" and returned it. It is displaying all the backslashes in browser also. The backslashes are no taken as escape characters. They are getting printed as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `net.sf.json` json library, both `jsonObject` and `jsonObject.toString()` provide output values without string escape character. Which library you are using..?

Also try returning the original `jsonObject` itself than the one converted with `toString`. It might give you the desired result.
Alternate option would be to unescape the string which is send to browser. You can use stringescapeutils from `org.apache.commons.lang` for this 
 `return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(resultSet.toString()) ;`

Comment: Tried it. But adding this function didnt make any difference to the output. :( :(